# How to use GDAL in java classes with Eclipse?

Tags: gdal, java, eclipse

I want to use GDAL in java classes with Eclipse.

I had gdal.jar to the build path but it does not work ("Native library load failed. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path").

I try to add libraries (gdalconstjni.dll + gdaljni.dll + ogrjni.dll + osrjni.dll) and to modify environment variables (as some tutorials advocated) but without success.

What should I do to use GDAL in my java classes with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a 32/64 bits system issue.  Here is the link to download usefull libraries : http://download.gisinternals.com/release.php